# Why do I have to have rep50 to answer someone else's question?

Tags: support, privileges

Seriously, I have the answer to someone's question. But if this takes too long, they won't get it. I don't time to to receive internet blessings.

Comment: FWIW, I think you are confusing answering (1 rep, except in limited cases) with "comment everywhere" which requires 50 rep.  Try answering, and ask on meta if you have problems.

Comment: I've got 21k rep and still haven't gotten Internet Blessings as a perk. I'm starting to think it's a scam.

Answer (score 15):

You don't need 50 rep to answer someone's question. You can do so right away!

The different levels of reputation needed for certain actions are called [privileges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

The ones relevant to you are:

- **1: create posts**
  Ask a question or contribute an answer
- **10: remove new user restrictions**
  Post more links, answer protected questions
- **50: comment everywhere**
  Leave comments on other people's posts

As you can see, you only need 1 point of reputation to participate. This allows you to ask questions, answer them, and comment on your own questions and answers.

Some questions are *protected*. They have a notice that reads "highly active question". To answer those, you need to have earned 10 points of reputation. Since you get those for just one single up vote on a post (question or answer) of yours, that's not that big a hurdle.

What you *do* need 50 points of reputation for, is commenting on every possible post (not just your own). What I think happened, is that you tried to answer in a comment. That's exactly what the threshold is there for. Scroll down a bit, and you'll find a big text box captioned "Your Answer". That's where your answer should go. This allows other users to vote on it, which earns you reputation.

For more information, please see [the help](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/help) or take [the tour](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/tour).